# Golang for loop continues counting

Tags: go

I am trying to make a for loop stop when a string contains a certain numeral. The only problem is it stops adding value to the string after adding 31 to the counter. I feel it is going to fast before it can play catch up. I know there's always another way to complete the task but I would just want to understand why it does this.

What I'm trying to accomplish is having the counter act as the height. The **theSlice = 8** and **webSlices** is a list. The whole text says "Height is a 1" so I am trying to see what number is the height and make counter equal that.

Code:

```
func breakDownSlice(theSlice int, webSlices []string) {
counter := 0
done := false
for done == false {
    log.Println(webSlices[theSlice])
    log.Println(counter)
    done = strings.Contains(webSlices[theSlice], string(counter))
    if done == true {
        log.Printf("The height is %d", counter)
    } else {
        counter++
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share input and the output you're getting? What's the value of `webSlices[theSlice]`?

Comment: webSlices[theSlice] = "Height is a 1"

Output is  "The height is 1" and goes on to "The height is 32" 

It should stop at 1 but it goes till 32.

Comment: If that's the output, then this can't be the code you're running, right? I don't see how the `%d` formatting could produce `1-32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line

```
done = strings.Contains(webSlices[theSlice], string(counter))
```

`string(counter)` can't work here, use `strconv.Itoa(counter)` instead

Comment: @GoofBall101   then set my answer as the answer of your question please